# SetWindowActivationScope. Cocoa equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos-carbon

A Carbon window could be made to appear always active (regardless of whether it is the active window) by:

`SetWindowActivationScope( window, kWindowActivationScopeIndependent );`

Any idea how I can achieve same with a Cocoa window?